# Elasticsearch conflicts with existing mapping in other types

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, mapping, laravel-scout

I'm very new in Elasticsearch, I'm implementing it inside my Laravel project with [Elasticsearch Scout Driver](https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver#tutorial) but I've got an error while insert model object inside index.

The model is a **Post**, made like this:

```
>>> $post = App\Models\Post::first();
=> App\Models\Post {#853
     id: 1,
     title: "First Post",
     description: "My first post",
     created_at: "2017-09-13 13:31:51",
     updated_at: "2018-02-16 16:23:44",
     deleted_at: null,
   }
```

Inside model class, I declare the mapping options, I report my mapping options:

```
// Map elements to be saved in Elasticsearch
protected $mapping = [
    'properties' => [
        'id' => [
            'type' => 'integer',
            'index' => false
        ],
        'title' => [
            'type' => 'text'
        ],
        'description' => [
            'type' => 'text'
        ],
        'created_at' => [
            'type' => 'date',
            'ignore_malformed' => true,
            'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        ],
        'updated_at' => [
            'type' => 'date',
            'ignore_malformed' => true,
            'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        ],
        'deleted_at' => [
            'type' => 'date',
            'ignore_malformed' => true,
            'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        ]
    ]
];
```

Every time I call `$post->searchable();` to put my model inside my Elasticsearch index, I've got this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Mapper for [deleted_at] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [deleted_at] has different [format] values]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Mapper for [deleted_at] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [deleted_at] has different [format] values]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I'm guessing that the problem is the `null` value of `deleted_at` property.
**I need** `deleted_at == null` because I manage `soft deletion` with **Laravel**: any another value will cause the soft deletion for Laravel framework (not retrieve element when query).

As you can see, I tried to put `ignore_malformed => true` but it doesn't work for me.
I tried to add another option `null_value => NULL` without success.

Where I am wrong?

How can I insert posts inside my Elasticsearch Index with `deleted_at` attribute set to `null` **OR** set to date with format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`?

Thanks

PS: I'm using Elasticsearch Version 6.1.2.

Comment: Which version of  elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version: 6.1.2.

Comment: @Tenaciousd93 can you please post the resolution

Comment: @vvr02 I don't know how I resolved: as say Jettro Coenradie, from Elasticsearch 6+ multiple types in single index are no more allowed (see docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html) ). I decided to delete my index and fallowed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@babenko.i.a/how-to-make-laravel-and-elasticsearch-become-friends-55ed7690331c) to create a new index for each type I have. It seems working, maybe this was the solution.

Comment: @Tenaciousd93 thanks for the tutorial link, I will go though it.

Answer (score 1):

An index consists of multiple types (in version 6 this is no longer possible mainly due to this reason). The problem with different types is that they cannot store the same field name with a different mapping. This has to do with the way it is stored in Lucene.

Could it be you are inserting documents in two different types? Maybe by accident (Typo in the type while ingesting documents for instance). Then it might try to create a different field type by dynamic mapping say a string. This would cause the exception that you mention.

Comment: I'm using Version: 6.1.2, and I would like to insert more types inside my index (now I'm trying to insert `posts`, maybe later I would like to insert `hashtags` too). But in this particular case, I'm saving only posts. The field I'm getting the error is `deleted_at` that in my mySQL DB is a `datetime` field `nullable`.

Comment: Please add the output of the mapping of your index, I think I can explain better what I mean then.

Comment: My index is empty, newly created. The mapping options are already reported in my question and the output error is reported in question too. Do you need something else? Thanks.

Comment: I read about [single type for index from version 6.X](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html), it means that I have to create an index for each table of my mySQL DB that I would insert in my index? For example, the **posts** will be stored in index `post ` and the **hashtags** will be stored in index `hashtag`, am I right?

Comment: I noticed the mapping you have created, but I am curious about the mapping as it is seen from elastic. Use the _mapping endpoint. And related to the index for every table you are right, unless you can combine some tables into a single document structure.